# Automatic resyncing table in mysql between many servers

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some solution for automatic resyncing / replicating one table from one mysql server to many others.

I don't need master / slave solution, because the servers are not connected in this way, but there are some tables, where only on one server this table is changed and the other servers need the actual table as well.

Some ideas how to make this? Is there maybe some deamon what is watching for changes in background and synchronizing the tables if there are changes.

Of course I can programm my own tool for synchronizing the tables, but as first I want to ask if there is some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

[tungsten replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) does a lot of replication special cases. It can probably help you.

Configure all MySQL servers that change the table as masters, and then create a ring or fan out these changes to the others.